# SSMS Replace Unique Text in Constraint

Tags: regex, ssms, replace

Good day to everyone!

My question is simple to ask, but I haven't been able to do it.

I've generated a script for a database and its contents, now I would like to compare what I generated in one db against another.

Using winmerge, I've had difficulty since there are items like:

```
    CONSTRAINT [PK__onepk__321403CF014925CB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Where one script has 321403CF014925CB and another has 321403CF07820F21.

How can i replace all these texts so that it just becomes

```
    CONSTRAINT [PK__onepk__] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

of course, there are about a hundred primary keys under this condition.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Just a thought... [Red Gate's SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) allows you to ignore various differences between databases - one of which is constraint names.  Also, there's a two week free trial.

Comment: Thank you, Michael -- sadly, I'll need this far longer than two weeks.. and I can't justify the cost :(

Comment: Hi -- does anyone have an alternative solution?

Comment: Can anyone else give it a try? I still can't get the below answer to work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
CONSTRAINT \[PK__onepk__([\w^\]]+)\] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Given this input string:

```
CONSTRAINT [PK__onepk__321403CF014925CB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

This part of the expression

```
([\w^\]]+)
```

Will match

```
321403CF014925CB
```